# Has been/has gone

Tags: usage, present-perfect, been-vs-gone

Which one is grammatically correct
"Jack has never been to America"
or
"Jack has never gone to America"

Comment: Can you tell us what you think and why so people can help you better?

Comment: Both are grammatical, but the first is more _idiomatic_.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using have gone to / been to / been in](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/115858/using-have-gone-to-been-to-been-in)

Answer (score 2):

Generally, the difference between *been to America* and *gone to America* is that the first implies *and has come back* and the second doesn't.

(This is a special meaning of *been* - it doesn't work with any other form of *be*, so you can't say *I want to be to America*.)

However, in this case, the *never* neutralises the difference. As Kate Bunting says in a comment, *been* is more idiomatic, but both are grammatical, and in this case have no practical difference in meaning.